# perform summary functions in R on variables whose names match criteria

Tags: r

I'm a very novice R programmer trying to convert SAS code to R code.
I need to sum up the values for different variables separating by group. For example, my data will look something like this:

Area ID | Region | TRx_01_02_2014 | TRx_01_03_2014 | TRx_01_04_2014 | etc...

---001---|--EAST--|----------2.034--------|----------1.093--------|---------3.227-----------

---002---|--EAST--|----------0.119--------|----------4.002--------|---------7.327-----------

---001---|--WEST-|----------2.223--------|----------5.613--------|---------5.772-----------

There are over 80 different TRx_xx_xx_xxxx variables corresponding to different dates.  I need to sum up the TRx for each region for each date.

The old SAS code looked like this:

```
proc means data=example sum;
    class Region Area_ID;
    var TRx:;
    run;
```

The "var TRx:;" line would select every variable whose name began with the string "TRx" and then sum up that variable by the classes listed above (Region & Area_ID).  I'm looking for an equivalent way of doing that in R.  It would be very tedious to write out every single date for the TRx variables.  I've seen other posts about the grepl function that looks for patterns, but I'm not quite sure how to implement that in something like the data.table function which I've been using to do my summary functions.

To get sums I've been using this code:

```
>exampleList=Example[,list(sumTRx1=sum(TRx_01_02_2014),sumTRx2=sum(TRx_01_03_2014)),by=.(Region,Area_ID)]
```

I'd really hate to write out each and every sum that I need, so I'm wondering what the shortcut is for something like this.  I apologize if anything was unclear, this is my first time actually posting to this forum, as I've been able to find answers to all my other questions so far.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easily done with the `dplyr` package in R.

```
# install.packages('dplyr')
library(dplyr)

df = data_frame(area=c('001', '002', '001', '001'), 
                region=c('east', 'east', 'east', 'west'), 
                trx1=rnorm(4), trx2=rnorm(4), trx3=rnorm(4))
df
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#    area region       trx1       trx2       trx3
#   <chr>  <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1   001   east  0.6401357 -0.1601207 -0.4541891
# 2   002   east -1.0460221 -0.4339913  0.7096318
# 3   001   east -1.7173618 -0.9321431  1.9172886
# 4   001   west  1.2755188 -0.5356680 -1.7411916


df %>%
  select(region, area, starts_with('trx')) %>%
  group_by(region, area) %>%
  summarize_all(mean)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   region [?]
#   region  area      trx1       trx2       trx3
#    <chr> <chr>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1   east   001 0.7321764 -0.4147787  0.2116776
# 2   east   002 0.2855519  0.4735731 -0.4301295
# 3   west   001 0.5299542 -0.7694106  0.2509183
```

The `%>%` operator is read as "and then", so you take your data, and then select only the grouping variables (`region` and `area`) and the variables to average (all `trx`), and then summarize across all of the non-grouping variables by calculating the mean. You can replace `mean` with `sum` or `median` or `sd` or whatever other statistic you'd like to calculate as well.

### UPDATE

In order to get the total value of all `trx` variables, by `region` and `area`, we just need to change a couple of things:

```
df %>%
  select(region, area, starts_with('trx')) %>%
  mutate(total = rowSums(select(df, starts_with('trx')))) %>%
  group_by(region, area) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(total))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
#   region  area     total
#    <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
# 1   east   001 -2.869915
# 2   east   002  1.615576
# 3   west   001 -2.540118
```

The `mutate` line is where we create the total of all `trx` variables for each row. We just feed in a data frame into the `rowSums` function and let it do it's thing. From there, we group by `region` and `area` and then sum all of the `total` values.

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thank you so much!!

Comment: One more related question:
Now I need to sum up all the TRx variables for region and area.  Now instead of summing each individual TRx variable, I'm summing all of them for that specific region & area.  So for "EAST 001"  I need a Total_TRx variable that is the sum of all TRx_xx_xx_xxxx..  I've seen the rowsum function, but again I'm having trouble implementing.  How can I do this?